# Adding subscription to graphQL 'createPost' function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to add a subscription for following create post function

inside main index.js I have imported PubSub like following

```
const { ApolloServer } = require ('apollo-server'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { PubSub } = require ('graphql-subscriptions'); 

const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const { MONGODB } = require('./config.js');

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubsub })
});

mongoose
.connect(MONGODB, {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => {

    console.log('MongoDB Connected');

    return server.listen({
        port: 5002
    })
})
.then((res) => {
        console.log(`Server running at ${res.url}`)
    })
```

inside type Definitions I have used the following

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

module.exports = gql`
        type Post
        {
            id: ID!
            body: String!
            createdAt: String!
            username: String!
        }
        type User
        {
            id: ID!
            email: String!
            token: String!
            username: String!
            createdAt: String!
        }
        type Mutation{
            register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
            login(username: String!, password: String!): User!
            createPost(body: String!): Post!
        }
        type Subscription {
        newPost(    
            id: ID!,
            body: String!,
            createdAt: String!,
            username: String!
        }
    `;
```

This is post.js resolver

```
const { UserInputError, AuthenticationError } = require('apollo-server');
const { argsToArgsConfig } = require('graphql/type/definition');
const Post = require('../../models/Post');
const checkAuth = require('../../util/check-auth');

const { validatePostInput } = require('../../util/validators');

module.exports = {

    Mutation:
    {
        async createPost(_, { body }, context)
        {
            const user = checkAuth(context);

            const newPost = new Post({
                body,
                user: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                createdAt: new Date().toISOString()
            });

            const post = await newPost.save();

            // Subscripion Start

            context.pubsub.publish('NEW_POST', {
                newPost: post,
              }).then(()=>{
                console.log("New Post Created, Subscription Triggered!")
              });

            // Subscripion End

            return post;
        },

        async deletePost(_, { postId }, context)
        
    },
    
    Subscription: 
    {
      newPost: {
        subscribe: (_, __, { pubsub }) => pubsub.asyncIterator('NEW_POST')
      }
    }
};
```

Then I export that resolver like this in index.js

```
const postsResolvers = require('./posts');
const usersResolvers = require('./users');

module.exports = {
    Mutation: {
        ...usersResolvers.Mutation,
        ...postsResolvers.Mutation
    },
    Subscription: {
       ...postsResolvers.Subscription 
    }
}
```

This is compiling successfully, but its showing following issue,

> Unable to reach subscription server
> [image]

---

**UPDATE 1**

Then I improved like this

```
const { ApolloServer } = require ('apollo-server'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { PubSub } = require ('graphql-subscriptions'); 

const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs');
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const { MONGODB } = require('./config.js');

const { createServer } = require('http');
const { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } = require('apollo-server-core');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');
const { useServer } = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/ws');

const express = require('express');

const pubsub = new PubSub();

const app = express();

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const httpServer = createServer(app);

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    schema,
    csrfPrevention: true,
    context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubsub }),
    cache: "bounded",
    plugins: [
      // Proper shutdown for the HTTP server.
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),

      // Proper shutdown for the WebSocket server.
      {
        async serverWillStart() {
          return {
            async drainServer() {
              await serverCleanup.dispose();
            },
          };
        },
      },
    ],
});


 const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
    server: httpServer,
    path: '/graphql',
  });

  const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

mongoose
.connect(MONGODB, {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => {

    console.log('MongoDB Connected');

    return server.listen({
        port: 5002
    })
})
.then((res) => {
        console.log(`Server running at ${res.url}`)
    })
```

but still its not functional

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

then I updated the index.js like following
this time its not showing unable to reach message

```
const { ApolloServer } = require ('apollo-server-express'); 
const { createServer } = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer } = require('apollo-server-core');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('@graphql-tools/schema');
const { WebSocketServer } = require('ws');
const { useServer } = require('graphql-ws/lib/use/ws');
const { PubSub } = require ('graphql-subscriptions'); 
const resolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const typeDefs = require('./graphql/typeDefs');
const { MONGODB } = require('./config.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const pubsub = new PubSub();

(async function(){

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers });

const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);

const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
      server: httpServer, 
      path: '/graphql'
    });

const serverCleanup = useServer({ schema }, wsServer);

const server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      csrfPrevention: true,
      cache: 'bounded',
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req, pubsub }),
      plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer }),
        {
          async serverWillStart() {
            return {
              async drainServer() {
                await serverCleanup.dispose();
              },
            };
          },
        },
      ],
  });

 await server.start();
 server.applyMiddleware({ app });
 
 mongoose.connect(MONGODB, {useNewUrlParser: true});
 
 const PORT = 5002;
 httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
   console.log(
     `Server is now running on http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`,
   );
 });
})();
```

now showing following unable to connect to *ws://localhost:5002* error only

[image]

Comment: You didn't create and setup your `WebSocketServer`. Therefore it's not reachable. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/

Comment: @W.S. I have updated the question, still subscription server not trigger

Comment: So you can successfully connect to the websocketserver? What is returned by `await newPost.save()`? I believe your `post` variable is not a Post object and I guest you can just publish `newPost` (if `id` is set during saving). `pubsub.publish('NEW_POST', { newPost: newPost })`

Comment: still not showing, still its not Listening to subscription server,as my last image

Comment: Your access the playground through http (non ssl), while the websocket is trying the access the server through wss (ssl). That's strange behaviour. It's either both non-ssl (http + ws) or both ssl (https + wss). You need to figure our why this is not in sync.